# Led reactive to bass preout from headunit

Tags: voltage, amplifier, led-strip, music

I am stuck with the following problem. And please keep in mind that my understanding of electronics is not the best, I am simply asking for advice on building my project.

I have created a circuit where the leds will flash accordingly to music from a headphone input. Everyone has seen these, using tip31c transistors. However I am planning to put this to use in my car. I have decided that instead of using headphones (because i can only get it to work on aux on this current circuit, not fm, usb, bluetooth ect,) I will use the sub pre out on the back of the headunit as the input in place of the headphones. (See circuit in link)

Now here it is, the leds will only flash when the volume is turned up very loud. The tip31 transistor is obviosly not receiving enough voltage to activate the leds. To my understanding I will need to up the voltage recieved by the transistor base pin. According to the headunit specs the pre outs are max 5v.

[Edit] I would like to know how I can boost the signal from the pre out to the tip31. The signal would be very very small, half of a volt probably (on low volumes). I am looking at a way to increase this so my leds are driven on low volumes. Currently (no pun intended) the output only reaches a level that can activate the leds once it is, probably, at about 2 - 3 volts. Can anyone provide me with a solution to increading the recieved signal to base pin of the transistor.

This is essentially what I've done:

[image]

This is my headunit. Google it to find an image of the rear. I want to use one of the black preouts instead of an aux. http://www.sony.com.au/product/wx-gt90bt

Comment: A circuit diagram of what you currently have working is required.

Comment: *"Sub pre out on the back of the headunit"*.  Huh? What? Way too much hand waving. -1 for the sloppy writing, and closing this mess because being too painful to read all the way, I can't tell what is being asked.

Comment: I am asking about upscaling the volume coming from the sub output on the headunit to drive my leds on lower volumes.  And I'm sorry I do not know how to add images

Comment: I don't think you have enough rep to post an image, but post a link to it and someone can edit it into the question.

Comment: I have now added links, I hope this helps clarify what I am trying to achieve. I am sorry if no one likes the way I have asked my question but I, to the best of my ability, have tried to outline my problem and have come here to seek advice and not scrutiny. Please help me out, I was advised that this was the best place to seek answers.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop: Modern car stereo systems often are broken into two units: the so-called "head unit" that mounts in the vehicle dashboard and the remainder of the system in another box hidden elsewhere within the vehicle. The external line outputs from the stereo system are generally located on the head unit. FWIW - the terms that the OP used are considered to be industry-standard terms in the automotive audio field.

Answer (score 1):

The 'step up' you need is more amplification of the line signal. Using a Darlington like TIP120 may be a solution in that direction, e.g. you can expect [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgdCtuc-yZQ).

Also, you've said nothing about what LEDs you're using. To flash the bog standard 20mA LEDs to music you don't need more than signal transistors (like 2N3904/2N3906), e.g. as seen [here](http://makezine.com/projects/easy-led-color-organ/) [the schematic symbol for the NPN transistor is wrong there by the way, something that none of the 30 or so commentators seem to have noticed], but you need to set up the right circuit; there is two-stage amplification there, much like a Darlington does. Transistors like TIP31 and TIP120 are power transistors capable of letting many amps through their collector-emitter.

To get good answers here you need to ask good questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, it's very helpful and is what I was looking for as I had no idea if I was on the right track. I will head out and get these components to test. I am using 5050 blue strip leds, I have 60 of them in strips of 15.

Comment: @Benjamin Cameron: You should add some details about those, googling found some RGB ones under that name https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAJOTzSoa3U